# How to keep the size of the button the same regarding the font-size is change during transition?

Tags: css, css-transitions

How to change font-size inside a button without changing the side of a button and without provoking changes in the nav?

As you can see in this website the question mark changes, but I need that to change alone. The nav or section and the button must not change.

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  border: .5px solid crimson;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 10px 0 crimson inset;
  margin: 10px;
}

.links {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}

#bshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

#bshark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}

#cshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color, font-size;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

#cshark:hover {
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="links">
  <a href=""><button id="bshark">Protective</button></a>
  <a href=""><button id="bshark">Destructive</button></a>
  <a href=""><button id="cshark">?</button></a>
</nav>
```

If you want to visualize the problem that I'm talking about you can visit this [website](https://www.free-singularity.org).

Thank you all for answering my questions not matter the silly they are.

Comment: Wrap your code with triple backticks ```code here```. Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well. You have the option to edit your post. Please do that

Comment: 10 answers and not a single up-vote for the question despite giving away half your rep. Here's one.

Comment: What you mean about not a single vote? I did vote.

Comment: When I viewed your question it had 10 answers but nobody had up-voted your question. I found it surprising that lots of people had taken all that time to write you an answer and potentially take your bounty without at least up-voting the question.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding these four properties to your **.links** selector:

```
    .links {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      ...existing
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uberrobert/kj8zobqd/6/

If necessary, you can adjust your **button** selector horizontal margins if you need exact spacing to sync w/your existing layout (e.g. margin: 10px 18px;) .  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, now it working as I imaging to do. The question is why, hahaha. I kind of learning.

Answer (score 3):

To keep the size of a button consistent during a font-size transition, you can use the transform property instead of directly animating the font-size property. By applying a scale transformation to the button, the size will appear consistent even if the font size changes.

```
button {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

 button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

In this example, the transition property is set on the button to specify the duration (0.3s) and easing function (ease) for the transformation. The transform property is then used to scale the button by applying the scale transformation. In the :hover state, the button is scaled to 1.1 times its original size.

By animating the transform property, the button will maintain its original dimensions, and any changes in font size will not affect the button's size during the transition.

Comment: I tried your code, the size of the button also changes.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the button text in a span element, display it as block, and scale on hover.

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  border: .5px solid crimson;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 10px 0 crimson inset;
  margin: 10px;
}

.links {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}

#bshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

#bshark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}

#cshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color, font-size;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

#cshark:hover {
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
}
/* ADD THIS CSS */
button span {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

 button:hover span {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="links">
  <a href=""><button id="bshark"><span>Protective</span></button></a>
  <a href=""><button id="bshark"><span>Destructive</span></button></a>
  <a href=""><button id="cshark"><span>?</span></button></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: i think your answers is good from others

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your HTML (button elements are not required) and format both your navbar and your buttons as flexboxes.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

nav>a {
  color: inherit;
  border: 1px solid crimson;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

nav>a:hover {
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="links">
  <a href="">Protective</a>
  <a href="">Preventive</a>
  <a href="">Disruptive</a>
  <a href="">Destructive</a>
  <a href="">?</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Although OP asked for a button solution this is still a good alternative so definitely useful.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

This is a [typography](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Baseline/Typography) related issue. Let us reproduce the issue first with a bit more exaggeration. In following demo I am increasing the font size of `?` to `40px` on hover.

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  border: .5px solid crimson;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 10px 0 crimson inset;
  margin: 10px;
}

.links {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}

#bshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

#bshark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}

#cshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color, font-size;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

#cshark:hover {
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="links">
  <a href=""><button id="bshark">Protective</button></a>
  <a href=""><button id="bshark">Destructive</button></a>
  <a href=""><button id="cshark">?</button></a>
</nav>
```

The default value of the property [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#formal_definition) is `baseline`. If you notice all the words are trying to align themselves on the same baseline. As the size of `?` increases other buttons get pushed down to remain on the same baseline.

### Solution

Simply use `vertical-align: middle` on the `#cshark` element:

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  border: .5px solid crimson;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 10px 0 crimson inset;
  margin: 10px;
}

.links {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}

#bshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

#bshark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}

#cshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color, font-size;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;

   /* SOLUTION */
   vertical-align: middle;
}

#cshark:hover {
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="links">
  <a href=""><button id="bshark">Protective</button></a>
  <a href=""><button id="bshark">Destructive</button></a>
  <a href=""><button id="cshark">?</button></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a second div with flex and auto margin with min-content width:

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  border: .5px solid crimson;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 10px 0 crimson inset;
  margin: 10px;
}

.links {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}

#bshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

#bshark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}

#cshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

#cshark:hover {
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.linksBtns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: min-content;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="links">
    <div class="linksBtns">
        <a href=""><button id="bshark">Protective</button></a>
        <a href=""><button id="bshark">Destructive</button></a>
        <a href=""><button id="cshark">?</button></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe correct answer you are looking for.

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  border: .5px solid crimson;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 30px 0 crimson, 0 0 10px 0 crimson inset;
  margin: 10px;
}

.links {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
  margin: 10px;
}

#shark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
}

#bshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

#bshark:hover {
  border-color: orange;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 40px !important;
}

#cshark {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition-property: border-radius, border, color, font-size;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  transition-timing-function: .1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

#cshark:hover {
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  ...existing
}
```

```html
<nav class="links">
  <a href=""><button id="bshark">Protective</button></a>
  <a href=""><button id="bshark">Destructive</button></a>
  <a href=""><button id="cshark">?</button></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the end of `#bshark` if this is your wanted behaviour

```
line-height: 20px;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 0;
height: 45px !important;
```

This sets `line-height` to be constant instead of changing on hover.

Comment: Perhaps the size does not change, but the button moves up, it changes somehow. I'm still not happy with this. I need the only thing to change, the font-size. Everything else must still the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `transform: scale()` to adjust the font size without affecting the button's size or the surrounding elements.

```
#cshark {
  font-size: 16px; 
  transform-origin: center; /* Set transform origin */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease; /* Apply transition */
}

#cshark:hover {
  font-size: 20px; /* Change font size on hover */
  transform: scale(1.25); /* Scale up the text size */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, your button is not resized, but re-aligned to center.

Just add `vertical-align: top;` to the `#cshark` selector.